# gnome-screensaver still trying to load after installing xscreensaver?

Tags: xscreensaver, gnome-screensaver

After installing `xscreensaver`, as detailed [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/114027/how-to-add-screensavers-to-ubuntu-12.04/), including removing gnome-screensaver, it still appears in the logs (`syslog`) that something is trying to launch `gnome-screensaver`:

```
 gnome-session[2563]: WARNING: Could not launch application 'gnome-
 screensaver.desktop': Unable to start application: Failed to execute child 
 process "gnome-screensaver" (No such fsuch file or directory)
```

How can I stop this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, used `sudo find / -iname "gnome-screensaver.desktop"`, which showed me the presence of `gnome-screensaver.desktop` in `/etc/xdg/autostart/`, which was responsible for still trying to load the now uninstalled gnome-screensaver at each startup. Removing this file removed the error from syslog.

Comment: this solution is still working, even for 16.04

Comment: Still working for 19.04. Had an issue with gnome-screensaver zombie, which was somehow resurrecting itself even after uninstall which would lead to the double login screen, with the exception that the second one was all broken and messed up. The only way was to hard-reboot when this happens.